# Install postman Ubuntu 18

Tags: software-installation

I migrated from ubuntu 16 to 18, and I want a quick way to install native Postman app. What's the quickest way? Can it be installed in the terminal?

Comment: why the downvote?

Answer (score 4):

I just see that it can be done with [Snap](https://codeburst.io/how-to-install-and-use-snap-on-ubuntu-18-04-9fcb6e3b34f9).

And in the terminal it is just:

```
snap install postman
```